# Advance to the next q in a quiz using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a quiz in php and I am having trouble advancing to the next question if they get the right answer. I want to stay on the same page.  I tried adding 1 to the primary key of the question if a right answer is submitted but that didn't seem to work.

```
   <?php
include('includes/config.inc.php');
?>
<?php  
    if ($_POST==true && array_key_exists('ans', $_POST)){


        $ans = $_POST['ans'];
        $question = $_POST['question'];


        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answer WHERE pk_answer = $ans;");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $correct=$row['correct'];   
        }
        echo $correct;
        if ($correct == 1) { 
         echo "You are so cool!!!!";
        } else {
            $msg = "You submitted an incorrect answer. Please try again.";
            $incorrect = $ans;
        }
    }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>G.A.M.E.</title>
<style>
    .incorrect {
        color: #F00;
        font-weight:bold;   
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <h3>ASTM SAFETY QUIZ QUESTION 1</h3>

  <?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz LIMIT 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $pk_quiz=$row['pk_quiz'];
    $fk_module=$row['fk_module'];
    $fk_task=$row['fk_task'];
    $quiz_benchmark=$row['quiz_benchmark'];
    $question=$row['question'];
?>
  <p><?php echo $question; }?></p>

<form id="quiz" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<?php  $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answer ORDER BY RAND()");
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
$pk_answer=$row2['pk_answer'];
$fk_quiz=$row2['fk_quiz'];
$answer=$row2['answer'];
$correct=$row2['correct'];
?>

      <input type="radio" name="ans" value="<? echo $pk_answer; ?>" id="RadioGroup1_0" />
      <?php if ($fk_answer =  $pk_quiz) {
                if ($incorrect == $pk_answer) {
                    echo '<span class="incorrect">'.$answer."</span>";
                } else {
                    echo $answer; 
                }
      }}?>
      <input name="question" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pk_quiz; ?>" />
    <br /><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</p>
</form>

<?php if ($msg == true) { echo $msg; } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You code seems to be outputting all the questions (`select * from quiz`), followed by all the answers to all the questions (`select * from answer`). so I'm having a little trouble understanding what you mean by "advance to the next question".

Comment: If you really want to "stay on the same page" (which to me means no page reloads or redirects), you'll need some javascript and ajax in there

Comment: THanks for the response! Here is the page so far: dearroomie.com/game/question.php I changed the LIMIT to 1 so it shows 1 question. When the user hits submit I want the page to refresh and either say that they were wrong or move on to the next question in the database. Hopefully that makes sense!